# String manipulation using MD5 in rails 3

Tags: ruby, md5

I have a big string

```
approx 4000 characters
```

i want encrypt and decypt it using MD5 because of i want to do convert in a small string please help me a lot of finding i found `Base64` but it is not our solution please any one help me

```
my_string="abcdefghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
      Base64.encode64(my_string)
```

it gives us very lengthy string.

Comment: I think we can only encrypt the string using MD5 not decrypt.

Comment: any another way to large string into small string using any conversion

Comment: Please decrypt your question first by adding punctuations in appropriate positions and doing appropriate capitalization.

Comment: It is good you have a correct answer now. However the question (and title) make no sense. Currently your question looks most like a request for help using MD5, but the accepted answer is something different. If you have time to correct that and explain what you really needed, that would be good. It is fine to mention that you tried MD5 and Base64, even though they are the wrong tools to do what you wanted, but please at least remove the words "encrypt" and "decrypt", and put your *real need* into the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting a string will not make it smaller, it will at best be the same length. I think what you are looking for is a way to [compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) your string. That aside, MD5 is a one-way [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) algorithm, that means that it is designed, so there is now way of recovering the source string (it turns out that it was designed rather [poorly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5#Security)).

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a one-way hash, you can't decrypt it.

To encode a string use `Digest::MD5.hexdigest('foobar')` but for most purposes I'd say use a better hashing algorithm; MD5 has been broken for a long time.

Comment: thanks for this answer but my main problem is that i have a big string and iwant to convert in a small string by the conversion any another way instead of md5